# gcloud auth use different serviceaccount

Tags: gcloud, service-accounts

When using Google Cloud, the cli has you authenticated as a particular user (`serviceaccount`, representing either a user or an "account" with limited permissions for a machine).

You can get your current `serviceaccount` with: `gcloud auth list` or list all service accounts and associated roles with `gcloud projects get-iam-policy [project_id]` or throughthe dashboard.

**How do you change `serviceaccounts` with for `gcloud` cli?** I don't believe [this](http://gcloud%20projects%20get-iam-policy) is it.

Use Case:

I am logged into a VM with GKE access as a developer without a`container.admin` role, which I need to modify my cluster. I don't want to add a `container.admin` role to this user, but want to switch to a `serviceaccount` that has this role temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

If the serviceAccount is shown when you run `gcloud auth list` you just need to run:

`gcloud config set account yourserviceAccount`.

If not, you need to [activate it to use it in gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account):

`gcloud auth activate-service-account yourserviceAccount --key-file credentialsFile.json`

To obtain a key-file you can run:

`gcloud iam service-accounts keys create [FILE_NAME].json --iam-account yourServiceAccount`